# Cannot handle camera in two fragments having video recorder and Camera capture

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, video-capture, android-mediarecorder

I am making Instagram like app in which there are different screens for capturing image and recording image. My problem is that when I run my app with both fragment then my app crashes leaving error :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
              at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
              at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:428)
              at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:389)
              at textileapp.ebizz.com.myapplication.VideoFragment.onCreateView(VideoFragment.java:55)
```

But when I ran my app with only one fragment either camera screen ot video recorder screen, then it works fine. But with both fragment together app crashes. Ca any one help with this.
My code:

**Camera Fragment**

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private View rootView;
    private Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback;
    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;
    LinearLayout capture;
    private int mId = 0;
    ImageView change_camera, flash_icon;
    private String mFlashMode="Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON";

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
        defineIds(rootView);
        handleClick();
        change_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2) {
                    releaseCamera();
                    chooseCamera();
                }
            }
        });
        flash_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mFlashMode.equalsIgnoreCase(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)) {
                            mFlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON;
                        } else if (mFlashMode.equalsIgnoreCase(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
                            mFlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF;
                        } else if (mFlashMode.equalsIgnoreCase(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
                            mFlashMode = Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO;
                        }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // stop and release camera
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    public void chooseCamera() {
        //if the camera preview is the front
        if (mId == 1) {
            camera = Camera.open(0);
            refreshCamera();
            mId=0;
        } else if (mId == 0) {
            camera = Camera.open(1);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            refreshCamera();
            mId=1;
        }
    }
    private void defineIds(View view) {
        capture = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.capture);
        change_camera= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.change_camera);
        flash_icon= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flash_icon);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Picture Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };
    }

    public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
        //take the picture
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    }

    public void refreshCamera() {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private void handleClick() {
        capture.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.capture:
                try {
                    captureImage(v);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // open the camera
            camera = Camera.open(0);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();

        // modify parameter
        param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        try {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
            // the preview.
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // check for exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        refreshCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // stop preview and release camera
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        camera.release();
    }
}
```

**Video Fragment**

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private ImageView record_image_button, change_camera;
    private Context myContext;
    private LinearLayout cameraPreview;
    private boolean cameraFront = false;
    private View rootView;


  /*  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }*/
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
//        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        myContext = getActivity();
        initialize();
        if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        if (mCamera == null) {
            // if the front facing camera does not exist
            if (findFrontFacingCamera() < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                change_camera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mCamera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }
    private int findBackFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the back facing camera
        // get the number of cameras
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        // for every camera check
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        cameraPreview = (LinearLayout)rootView. findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
        cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

        record_image_button = (ImageView) rootView. findViewById(R.id.record_image_button);
        record_image_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hold down the button to record video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        record_image_button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                    Log.e("CLCIKEVENT", String.valueOf(event));
                    if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        finish();
                    }
                    // work on UiThread for better performance
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // If there are stories, add them to the table

                            try {
                                mediaRecorder.start();
                            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                                // Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    recording = true;

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP||
                        event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Video captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    recording = false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        change_camera = (ImageView) rootView. findViewById(R.id.change_camera);
        change_camera.setOnClickListener(switchCameraListener);
    }

    View.OnClickListener switchCameraListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get the number of cameras
            if (!recording) {
                int camerasNumber = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
                if (camerasNumber > 1) {
                    // release the old camera instance
                    // switch camera, from the front and the back and vice versa

                    releaseCamera();
                    chooseCamera();
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone has only one camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void chooseCamera() {
        // if the camera preview is the front
        if (cameraFront) {
            int cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                // open the backFacingCamera
                // set a picture callback
                // refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                // mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        } else {
            int cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                // open the backFacingCamera
                // set a picture callback
                // refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                // mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other
        // applications
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
        // check if the device has camera
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean recording = false;
    View.OnClickListener captrureListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (recording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Video captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                recording = false;
            } else {
                if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    finish();
                }
                // work on UiThread for better performance
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // If there are stories, add them to the table

                        try {
                            mediaRecorder.start();
                        } catch (final Exception ex) {
                            // Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
                        }
                    }
                });

                recording = true;
            }
        }
    };

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // stop and release camera
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }}
```

**Camera Preview** for Video Record

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // create the surface and start camera preview
            if (mCamera == null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        refreshCamera(mCamera);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        //method to set a camera instance
        mCamera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // mCamera.release();

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
If anyone get then please help me with this.

Comment: There's no help in there. Android does not allow for two simultaneous connections to the camera. It's just how it works. A possible, but very complicate, alternative is to have your own private surface for the camera to connect to and then distribute it to each fragment that you want on screen. But again, that is a very very complex code.

Comment: Isn't any solution for that, means cant we close the connection to camera while swtching the fragment or anyhting else.

Comment: If you close then open again on the other fragment, then it should work. Look at the example of the Google Camera. But it have to be completely closed from one before the other can start.

Comment: can you please show me how to do that

Comment: I would probably have a singleton controlling a mutex. And on transition (assuming a viewPager, would be during `onPageSelected`) the fragment would check. But that's a fairly detailed code and I gotta work. But good luck!

Comment: ok buddy but whenever  you get anytime then pls help me then.

Comment: hey anyone here can tell me solution, i am stuck here from 2 weeks pls help me .

Comment: @DevBuddy Did u find any proper solution for same issue?

Comment: No i did not got any solution yet @Beena